# akka: how to test that an actor was stopped

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka

I am wondering what the canonical way is of testing whether an actor has stopped in akka. Here is an example of how I am currently doing; I'm worried I'm over complicating it.

```
import akka.actor.{Terminated, Actor, Props, ActorSystem}
import akka.testkit.TestProbe

class MyActor extends Actor {
  import MyActor._
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Stop => context.stop(self)
  }
}

object MyActor {
  def props = Props(new MyActor)
  case object Stop
}


object MyActorSpec {

  val system = ActorSystem()
  val myActor = system.actorOf(MyActor.props)
  val testProbe = TestProbe()

  case object MyActorStopped

  val watcher = system.actorOf(Props(new Actor {
    context.watch(myActor)
    override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
      case Terminated(`myActor`) => testProbe.ref ! MyActorStopped
    }
  }))

  myActor ! MyActor.Stop
  testProbe.expectMsg(MyActorStopped)
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can get rid of the separate watcher actor, and just watch the target actor directly from the `testProbe` actor:

```
val testProbe = TestProbe()
testProbe watch myActor
myActor ! MyActor.Stop
testProbe.expectTerminated(myActor)
```

See [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html#Watching_Other_Actors_from_Probes) for the relevant section of the Akka testing docs.

Comment: Excellent - I was hoping for something like this. Not sure how I missed it Cheers.

Comment: Would also like to add, when it difficult to obtain the `ActorRef` to pass to the `expectTerminated()` method e.g. the ref was created as a child of another actor, I have found it useful to capture the ref that was stopped and do checks on e.g. it's name: `val msg = testProbe.expectMsgType[Terminated]; assert(msg.actor.path.name == "myActor")`

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using the testActor instead of a testProbe?
`this watch myActor`
`myActor ! MyActor.Stop`
`expectTerminated(myActor)`

Comment: I like this solution, but is there a way to make it work with Akka Typed?  The TestProbe class in Akka Typed does not have a "watch" method.