# Watch an Akka actor from outside the actor system

Tags: java, akka

I have a unit test which looks something like this

```
ActorSystem system = ...
ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(...);

// Actor will create a child actor and send a message to the test actor
expectMsgClass(...)
ActorRef child = getLastSender();

// This message should cause child to exit
actor.tell("stopChild", null);

// Check that child has exited
????
```

It seems that the obvious way to implement the `????` is to watch the actor and expect the `Terminated` message.  `watch` is on `ActorContext`; do I need to create an actor to watch the child, or is it possible to do that outside of an actor?

I am looking to write something like

```
system.???.watch(child, getRef());
expectMsgClass(Terminated.class);
// Check that Terminated.actor is child
```

Can I do that?

Comment: Did you consider just using the TestProbe for this as mentioned in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084903/akka-how-to-test-that-an-actor-was-stopped , or is there a special reason you want to avoid the watching actor?

Comment: @awagen That answer creates a new actor class sto watch the actor in question.  I saw how to do that, but was wondering if there was a way to do it without creating a new class.